# Post запрос с исключенными полями XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, xmlparser, javax

Такая проблема.
У меня на пост запрос приходит String с xml.

```
<Message>
        <Recipients>
        </Recipients>
        <Substitutions></Substitutions>
        <Attachments></Attachments> 
        <Links></Links>
        <MessageSubject></MessageSubject>
        <MessageText></MessageText>
    </Message>
```

можно ли как то "оформить" Класс описывающий Message в java так чтобы можно было посылать сокращенный XML без полей и запрос не ломался.

например я послал вот такой запрос без половины полей и запрос бы не сломался.

```
<Message>
            <Links></Links>
            <MessageSubject></MessageSubject>
            <MessageText></MessageText>
        </Message>
```

класс оформлен сейчас так

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name="Recipients")
    private Recipients recipients;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Substitutions")
    @XmlElement(name="substitution")
    private ArrayList<Substitution> substitutions = new ArrayList<Substitution>();;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Attachments")
    @XmlElement(name="attachment")
    private ArrayList<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<Attachment>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Links")
    @XmlElement(name="link")
    private ArrayList<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();

    private String MessageSubject;
    private String MessageText;

конструкторы, геттеры и сеторы
}
```

Comment: Если Вы пришлёте сокращенный вариант, у Вас просто недостающие поля будут не заданы - никаких проблем не должно быть. Если у Вас есть проверка входящего XML, то менять надо ее, а не модель.

Comment: да точно дело было в валидаторе спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы пришлёте сокращенный вариант, у Вас просто недостающие поля будут не заданы - никаких проблем не должно быть. Если у Вас есть проверка входящего XML, то менять надо ее, а не модель.